# Move cursor to final of input while it is highlithing the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highlight

I need to put the cursor at final of input because it is going at start, it highlights the text so it goes to start.

I tried using `this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;` but it doesn't work pretty well or maybe i am puting it in the wrong line.

Thanks :)

```js
window.setInterval(function() {
  change();
}, 1);

function change() {
  $(function() {
    var elem = $('#code');

    highlighter(' new ', elem, "red");
    highlighter(' button', elem, "blue");
  });

  function highlighter(word, elem, color) {
    var html = elem.html();
    var reg = new RegExp(word, "g");

    html = html.replace(reg, "<span class='" + color + "'>" + word + "</span>");

    elem.html(html);
  }
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="code" contenteditable="true">
  new button
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elem = $('#code');

window.setInterval(function(){
  change();
}, 1);
function change(){
  $(function(){
    highlighter(' new ', elem,"red");  
    highlighter(' button', elem,"blue"); 
  });

function highlighter(word, elem, color){
  var html = elem.html();
  var reg = new RegExp(word,"g");
  html = html.replace(reg, "<span class='"+color+"'>" + word +"</span>");
  elem.html(html);
}
function addEvent(elem, event, fn){
if(elem.addEventListener){
  elem.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
}else{
  elem.attachEvent("on" + event,
  function(){ return(fn.call(elem, window.event)); });
}}

addEvent(elem,'focus',function(){
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function(){ that.selectionStart = that.selectionEnd = 10000; }, 0);
});
```

Below code should work actually but however because of browser issues looks like not working.

```js
this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
```

To load this properly I have added time out to get away this

```js
setTimeout(function(){ that.selectionStart = that.selectionEnd = 10000; }, 0);
```

Comment: The problem is i don't know where to put, can you send it already implented on my code ? please :)